# Typescript, React: set array object to state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    menuCatalog: true,
    menuCommon: true,
    fetched_data: []
});
```

This is an example of fetched data I try to set to the state property "fetched_data":

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "some_name", "ip": "127.0.0.1", "port": 5353}, {"id": 2, "name": "some_name", "ip": "128.0.0.1", "port": 5353}]
```

This is how I try to set it:

```
const fetched_stuff = await fetchStuff();

const fetched_data = fetched_stuff["data"];

setState({
    fetched_data
});
```

And this is error I get:

```
Argument of type '{ fetched_data: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ menuCatalog: boolean; menuCommon: boolean; fetched_data: never[]; }>'.
Type '{ fetched_data: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ menuCatalog: boolean; menuCommon: boolean; fetched_data: never[]; }': menuCatalog, menuCommon  TS2345
```

Tried a dozen different things, no solutions online help. How to actually set the array of objects to the state in typescript.react?

Comment: What about ```setState({menuCatalog: true,menuCommon: true,fetched_data});```?

Comment: @yudhiesh I think it should be `setState(prev => ({...prev, fetched_data}))`. It's possible that the booleans may not always be true.

Comment: @yudhiesh What about setState({menuCatalog: true,menuCommon: true,fetched_data});?  
Ofc. I tried that, and it says this:  
    Argument of type '{ stations_info: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ menuCatalog: boolean; menuCommon: boolean; stations_info: never[]; }>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should overwrite the previous state using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Your default state was

```js
{
    menuCatalog: true,
    menuCommon: true,
    fetched_data: []
}
```

However, when you later updated it, you only passed in `fetched_data`, which TypeScript recognized as an error because the original state also expects a `menuCatalog` and `menuCommon` property. What you should do be doing instead is that when updating the state, just use the functional update where properties of the previous state is passed, while the property you want to update is added at the end. This ensures your new state still has the old properties as well as the new property.

```js
setState(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  fetched_data
}))
```